# Mule 3.5.0 - Read large dat file and map to csv (in Mule CE)

Tags: csv, deployment, dictionary, mule, mule-studio

I'm looking for a way to build a Mule application that will read a large dat file (~800k rows) and map some of it's fields to a new csv file (with different headers) as output. I'm running the Community Edition of Mule so I'm unable to use the DataMapper tool. I've also looked at the CSV to Maps/Maps to CSV tools in conjunction with an in-memory DB, however these transformers also appear unavailable when using the Mule CE Server Runtime.

I need to package this application (as a war) and deploy it to an application server in the long-term, so I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to do that. I understand that even in EE the DataMapper tool still isn't fully supported by application servers. I've been stuck on this for a while now so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at FlatPack: http://flatpack.sourceforge.net/

From the doc:

> FlatPack should integrate nicely with Mule, the open source choice for integration and SOA.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDossot. I actually tried FlatPack when attempting to use the CSV to Maps/Maps to CSV tools. The issue I have is that I only need a subset of the incoming columns in the .dat file, which map to a subset of columns (different column names) in the output file. The DataMapper would have been perfect for this but isn't an option. Do you know of an example which demonstrates how I could do this with FlatPack (or similar)? Thanks.

Comment: You can use an `expression-transformer` to transform the rows parsed by FlatPack into the format you want for the output.